# Python module search path

Tags: python, path, module

I have a project like that :

```
foo/
| main.py
| bar/
| | module1.py
| | module2.py
| | __init__.py
```

with `main.py` doing `import bar.module1` and `module1.py` doing `import module2`.

This works using python 2.6 but not with python 3.1 (`ImportError: No module named module2`)

Why did the behaviour change ? How to restore it ?

Comment: Can you show the content of your __init__.py please ?

Comment: It's empty. In fact, to reproduce this behaviour, you can just have main.py and module1.py containing import statements and other files empty.

Comment: This seems like an odd structure, though I don't put my modules into packages that often; why not have the `__init__.py` import components that you care about in `main.py`

Comment: Why is that odd ? If I add `import module1` in __init__.py, it ends with (`ImportError: No module named module1` in 
`foo/bar/__init__.py`)

Comment: That does seem strange too; though if you did that, it would be cured by my answer as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In module1.py, do a: `from . import module2`

#### main.py

```
import bar.module1
print(bar.module1.module2.thing)
```

#### bar/**init**.py

```
#
```

#### bar/module1.py

```
#import module2 # fails in python31
from . import module2 # intrapackage reference, works in python26 and python31
```

#### bar/module2.py

```
thing = "blah"
```

As for why/how, that's above my paygrade.  The documentation doesn't seem to elucidate it.  Maybe in Python 3 they decided to enforce submodules in packages being explicitly imported with the intrapackage style?

- http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references
- http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references

Comment: Also referenced in [What's new in Python 3.0](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html): "The only acceptable syntax for relative imports is `from .[module] import name`. All import forms not starting with `.` are interpreted as absolute imports."